# how connect multiple client to a server in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, tcp, chat

I want to create a **chatroom** that in it 3 (or more device ) connect to a server with Tcp protocol on hotspot and server and clients cant talk to each other
this is my code that in 
when app start it try to connected to server (if existed) if it don't find server then it run server socket an wait for client  **but** **only one client** can connect to server and send and receive message
 i know that i have to use multi-thread but i can't handle this please help me:(

```
 package com.app.wifi_chat;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import com.uncocoder.app.wifi_chat.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class WifiChatActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler          handler = new Handler();
    private TextView         text;
    private EditText         input;
    private Button           btnSend;
    private Socket           socket;
    private DataOutputStream outputStream;
    private BufferedReader   inputStream;

//try to connect to server if find it return true 
    private boolean searchNetwork() {
        log("Connecting...");

        String range = "192.168.1.";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
            String ip = range + i;
            try {
                //log("Try IP: " + ip);
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 9000), 10);

                log("Connected!");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        return false;
    }

//run server and wait for new client
    private void runChatServer() {
        try {
            log("Waiting for client...");

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            log("A new client Connected!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        //server
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
//first time check for connect to server if not to find it then run server and wait for client
                if ( !searchNetwork()) {
                    runChatServer();
                }

                try {
                    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                }
                catch (IOException e1) {
                    log("Error: Connection is not stable, exit");
                    shutdown();
                }
//listen to client for get messeage
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        String message = inputStream.readLine();
                        if (message != null) {
                            log(message);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {}
                }
            }
        });
//send message to client or server
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (outputStream == null) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    String message = input.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

//log  messeage form client or server
    private void log(final String message) {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long time = timestamp % 1000000;

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText(text.getText() + "\n @" + time + ": " + message);
            }
        });
    }

//when app is kill close socket 
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            shutdown();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    private void shutdown() {
        try {
            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
```

Comment: forgive me for poor language

Comment: You don't have to post that xml file. 'if ( !searchNetwork()) {
                    runChatServer();
                }'. You did not explain this code. You should start with explaining this code. After you have done that explain the rest.

Comment: ok,i add description

Comment: that `socket = serverSocket.accept();` goes in a loop. voila.

Comment: i try this but still not work:(

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: when i put socket = serverSocket.accept(); in loop sever and client notice connection but message not send between

Comment: I don't see that loop in your code. And you did not tell why messages are not send in between. You did not tell why it does not work.

Comment: i test it and i don't know what is problem but i guess each new connection need new thread to listen or send data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a total mess.

Commonly you need to make something like this

class ClientClass implements Runnable //For managing clients
{
    Socket socket;

```
public ClientClass(Socket s)
{
    socket = s;
}

void run()
{
    //Get InputStreams
    //Manage client
}
```

}

```
ServerClass

while(true)
{
    new Thread(new ClientClass(server.accept()));//Maybe you want to store it for future comunication
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Nanoc,@greenapps and @njzk2 i solved my problem by you and  this pdf http://carfield.com.hk/document/java/tutorial/socket_chat.pdf